# How to show cfm, html, js, css, and browser tab in coldfusion builder 3?

Tags: tabs, coldfusion

On Coldfusion Builder 2, I see these tabs are available when I create a new page, but not on Coldfusion Builder 3.

[image]

What should I do to show them on CFB 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, they've taken out the different cfm, html, js and css tabs because now the same editor handles (and makes suggestions for) all those code types without having to switch editor windows.

As for the browser tabs, I haven't come up with any suitable replacement for them, except clicking the green Run button to display it in the actual browser.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I struggled w/ the same thing.

I figured out a solution...

- right-click in the editor
- choose **Open With**
- *Web Browser*

**Browser in CFB3:**
[image: Image1]

**NOTE:** if *Web Browser* isn't listed there, then choose **other** & **Internal Web Browser** -

**Internal Web Browser** under option '**Other**'
[image: Image2]